# Ubuntu Server: Networking fails with MODPROBE option in /etc/network/interfaces ...?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ftp, modprobe

For some reason (which I haven't been able to determine yet), yesterday morning the networking service on our web server (running Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS -- hardy) wouldn't start, and our website went down.

I noticed the following error message when trying to restart it:

```
* Reconfiguring network interfaces...
/etc/network/interfaces:6: option with empty value
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
   ...fail!
```

Line 6 in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file concerned a MODPROBE command, which (I believe) loaded in the `ip_conntrack_ftp` module so that I could use PASV on my FTP server (vsftpd): (breaking modprobe commands commented out below)

```
# Used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8). See the interfaces(5) manpage or
# /usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples for more information.
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe
#$MODPROBE ip_conntrack_ftp
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules

# The primary network interface
# Uncomment this and configure after the system has booted for the first time
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
    dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.4 xxx.xxx.xxx.5
```

I've verified that there is a file in `/sbin` called `modprobe`.

Like I said earlier, this setup had been working flawlessly until yesterday morning (though my bosses say that the site actually went down the previous night at 11 PM EST).

Can anyone shed some light on (A) why this broke, and (B) how can I re-enable the `ip_conntrack_ftp` module?

Comment: Did that ever work? At least current Ubuntu docs don't mention modprobe in interfaces(5) with a single word.

Answer (score 1):

Can anyone shed some light on **(A) why this broke**,

I don't think you can just execute modprobe from `/etc/networking/interfaces`. You need likely need to use the `pre-up` directive:

From the [interfaces(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/interfaces.5.html) manpage:

> ```
>    pre-up command
>           Run  command  before bringing the interface up.  If this command
>           fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
>           configured,  prints  an  error message, and exits with status 0.
>           This behavior may change in the future.
> ```

However it is preferable to add the name of the module to `/etc/modules` so it is loaded at boot time. (Notice that if the command `pre-up` command fails to execute your interface won't come up - even if the rest of the configuration is perfectly fine).

**and (B) how can I re-enable the ip_conntrack_ftp module?**

From the [modules(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man5/modules.5.html) manpage:

> ```
>    The  /etc/modules file contains the names of kernel modules that are to
>    be loaded at boot time, one per line. Arguments can  be  given  in  the
>    same line as the module name. Lines beginning with a ’#’ are ignored.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-enable the module by adding its name to /etc/modules .

Answer (score 0):

try to run command:

> modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp

and if it works fine, that means the module is being loaded fine.
then instead of adding modules every time the interfaces are restarted, add the above command to /etc/rc.local

then the module will remain loaded into system, all the time.(instead, it tried to load itself when network service starts)

Alternatviely, for testing, you can add this command "/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp" at the place of two lines commented with "MODPROBE", and then try if it works.